# Where, exactly, is the Boeing 727's FDR located?

Tags: flight-data-recorder, boeing-727

I'm working on a history report and I am trying to find a diagram that shows where the flight data recorder would have been on a Boeing 727 in 1984, specifically for Eastern Airlines. I know the general answer is "tail section," but I'm looking for a specific location, ideally with a diagram.

Comment: Hopefully someone can confirm this but in the freight conversion 727 it was in the rear cargo hold, just aft of the door. But I might be thinking of DC-10. It's been many years.

Comment: That’s true of the freighter. I don’t believe it was moved from the passenger version either, but I am not 100% sure of that.

Comment: I’m specifically asking about a passenger plane (sorry for being unclear). I know the CVR is in a cylindrical orange tube near the aft staircase, but I’m looking for the FDR’s precise location.